# Changing 'Open Dash' shortcut in Unity only partially working

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, chromebook

I'm using a Chromebook, so my keyboard is missing a 'Super' key.

Changing the shortcut in the keyboard settings, Unity Tweak Tool or CCSM to the 'Search' key doesn't work. Other keys work, but from using Gnome for a long time, where the Shortcut works by default, it is already in my worklow. The Chromebook community sadly couldn't help me on this :(

Is there any other way to change this shortcut?